# How to enter comments in React: What is the equivalent of html <!-- -->?

Tags: reactjs

In html to create a comment we use:

```
  <!-- Write your comments here -->
```

What is its equivalent in React while using React components in the return section of a react component? Sometimes I just want to place some comments like

```
   <!-- <MyComponent .... /> -->
```

but I can not do it in this way

Comment: Here you go {/*comments*/}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do regular HTML comments in jsx, the closest you can get is JS-style comments -

`{/* This is a comment */}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap in curly braces, and then block comment: `{/* <div /> */}`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments. You can write comments in React like below

```
  { /* <MyComponent .... /> */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can add comment in React code on the one line

```
// comment
```

Comment in other place than is html tags for more rows

```
/* comments*/
```

Answer (score 0):

But comment can add and to return part of class with `{/* coments*/}`. This away can get possibility write comments to more lines, like is can write comments to Java, C++, Javascript

Answer (score -1):

write comments as you might do in HTML and XML with `<!-- -->` syntax.
will throw Unexpected token error.

To write comments in JSX, you need to use JavaScript’s forward-slash and asterisk syntax, enclosed inside a curly brace `{/* comment here */}`.

Here’s the example:

```
export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Commenting in React and JSX~ </h1>
          {/* <p>My name is Bob</p> */}
          <p>Nice to meet you!</p>
        </div>
      );
}
```

[Ref](https://sebhastian.com/react-jsx-comments/)